# Implement table() function as a user defined function

Tags: r

```
x <- c(1,2,3,2,1)

table(x)
# x
# 1 2 3 
# 2 2 1
```

Outputs how many times each element occur in the vector.

I am trying to imitate the above function using `function()`

Below is my code:

```
TotalTimes = function(x){
  times = 0
  y = unique(x)
  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
      if(y[i] == x[i])
      times = times + 1
    }
    return(times)
  }
}
```

What would be the right approach?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one-liner, using `rle()`:

```
f <- function(x) {
    with(rle(sort(x)), setNames(lengths, values))
}

f(c(1,2,3,2,1))
# 1 2 3 
# 2 2 1
```

Alternatively, here's an option that's less "tricky", and is probably a better model for learning to code in an R-ish way:

```
f2 <- function(x) {
    ss <- sort(x)
    uu <- unique(ss)
    names(uu) <- uu
    sapply(uu, function(u) sum(ss == u))
}

f2(c(1,2,3,2,1))
# 1 2 3 
# 2 2 1
```

Comment: I wanted something which could be done using base R without any specific function

Comment: @NehalMishra This *is* base R.

Comment: @NehalMishra Probably not only the edited version. I looked through the revision history of this post and couldn't find anything that was not base R.

Answer (score 3):

```
function(x) {
   q = sapply(unique(x), function(i) sum(x == i))
   names(q) = unique(x)
   return(q)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method using base R:

```
# data
x <- c(1,2,3,2,1)

# set up
y <- sort(unique(x))
counts <- rep_len(0, length.out=length(y))
names(counts) <- y

for(i in seq_along(x)) {
  counts[x[i] == y] <- counts[x[i] == y] + 1
}
```

Wrapping it in a function:

```
table2 <- function(x) {
  # transform x into character vector to reduce search cost in loop
  x <- as.character(x)
  y <- sort(unique(x))
  counts <- rep_len(0, length.out=length(y))
  names(counts) <- y

  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    counts[x[i]] <- counts[x[i]] + 1L
  }
  return(counts)
}
```

This version only accepts a single vector, of course. At @Frank's suggestion, the function version is slightly different, and possibly faster, in that it transforms the input x into a character. The potential speed up is in the search in `counts[x[i]]` where the name in counts is referred to (as x[i]), rather than performing a search using "==."

Comment: `x`'s values only serve as names. Might as well just `x <- as.character(x)` as a first step inside the function so you can do `counts[x[i]] <- counts[x[i]] + 1L`